# App widget with listview

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I have some problem. I'm working with Android 2.2 and now I want to create widget with ListView. But after a lot of time as I seeking answer, I was discovered that it's impossible for this version. But maybe anyone know how I can realise similar effect? How I can to realize the effect of scrolling in `App Widget` in Android 2.2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make your question little more clear as what you exactly want....???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution for this question. I can use android-support library.

Comment: Hi, can you please share how exactly android-support-library can be used to have ListView in Widget in pre HoneyComb? Please site an example if you have one :)

Comment: @RagnaR can you give me example i am facing problem same like you.