# Updatable Listview Homescreen android

Tags: android, android-listview, homescreen

I want to create updatable `listview`.
I found great example here:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget

But `ListView` there is static.
I want to be able to update `listview` that I use on Homescreen `Widget` from app `mainActivity`.

**For example:**
I have some app activity:
With only 2 elements: `EditText` and `Button`

And I have some `homescreen widget` for this app with `ListView`
I want to be able to add `item` to the `ListView` when I clicking on `Button` in main app.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can catch an intent in your widget sent from the Button onClick listener.

Create an intent in your main app:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourWidget.class);
    intent.putExtra("data", "some data");
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

catch the intent in your widget:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    ListView lv = // your list

    // get data from the intent
    String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");

    // PREPARE YOUR view object

    lv.addView(view, position); // <- add to a specific position
    lv.addFooterView(view); //<- add to the bottom of the list

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how should I add `item` to the `listview`. And button is in the `mainapp` not on `Widget`.

Comment: I added some more details to the example.

Comment: ListView lv = // your list Are you sure that is possible in homsecreen Widget

Comment: no, I am not sure. I assumed you already placed one on your widget, but you don't know how to manipulate it. Have a look in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039339/how-can-i-build-an-appwidget-with-a-listview-while-using-the-support-library